# How do I integrate the MySpace API in my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, myspace

I want to integrate the MySpace API with my iPhone application. I tried using the MySpace demo application provided [here](http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/), but when I click on the login button it opens Safari and takes me to the MySpace login page.

I want to update status and mood within my application. Using their demo application as a basis, how is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at the authentication protocol myspace uses. For instance, twitter has changed their authentication mode and the user has to authenticate the application to use their account.

In case of twitter, you get the safari window only once to authenticate, after that you can execute code of the API without showing the safari url again.

Comment: has anyone successfully implemented myspace in iphone app.i need proper link to downlaod the sdk. Any help will be appreciated